# Crystal Report cross tab not showing data properly

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Hi guys I have crystal report and I want it to display the data like this:

[Correct Foramt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUI7C.png)

But I am getting an output when I am using cross tab as:

[Wrong Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Q6b.png)

Please advise me how can I fix this issue, I have tried to uncheck and and check cross tab keep together property in cross tab expert.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal automatically creates more horizontal pages if the crosstab doesn't fit on one page.

One option is to increase page width or reduce column widths.

Another option is to group the report and insert the CrossTab in a Group footer so that the content is divided across multiple CrossTab instances.